# Converting .spl spell files

Tags: spell-checking

VIM spell files seem to be in some binary format. Is it possible (and easy) to convert one back to a plain text word list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`:spelldump`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#%3aspelldump).

```
:spelld[ump]            Open a new window and fill it with all currently valid
                        words.  Compound words are not included.
                        Note: For some languages the result may be enormous,
                        causing Vim to run out of memory.
```

Vim will use the language file that you set with the `'spelllang'` option.